# How to create multiple records for each day in given quarter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have **Shift** model.

```
--- !ruby/object:Shift
attributes:
  id:
  starts_at:
  ends_at:
```

I want to add singelton method to create shifts for each day in given quarter.

```
class Shift

  def self.open_quarter(number, year)
    starts_at = "08:00"
    ends_at = "08:00"

    ...
  end
end
```

How to implement that in best way? I want that each shifts starts_at 8.00 am and finish 8.00 am on next day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def self.open_quarter(number, year)   
 start_time = Time.new(year, number*3 - 2, 1, 8) 

  while start_time.month <= number*3 && start_time.year == year
      Shift.create{starts_at: start_time, ends_at: start_time += 24.hours}
  end
end
```

make sure to set the correct timezone when using `Time.new`. Default is current timezone (see [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Time.html#method-c-new)). You can also use `Time.utc`.

Comment: Please add ``start_time.year == year`` to loop

Answer (score 1):

```
def self.open_quarter(number, year)
  starts_at = "08:00 am"
  ends_at = "08:00 pm"

  quarter_start = Date.new(year, (number * 3)).beginning_of_quarter
  quarter_end = Date.new(year, (number * 3)).end_of_quarter

  (quarter_end - quarter_start).to_i.times do |n|
    start_shift = "#{(quarter_start + n).to_s} #{starts_at}".to_datetime
    end_shift = "#{(quarter_start + n).to_s} #{ends_at}".to_datetime

    Shift.create(starts_at: start_shift, ends_at: end_shift)
  end
end
```